# docker not starting and failing with error , Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I am trying to start docker using the command:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

I am getting below error

```
Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.
```

I tried finding some suggestions over the web to resolve this issue and followed that but it didn't solve the issue.

> [Cannot start docker daemon in CentOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217526/cannot-start-docker-daemon-in-centos7)

This is my docker.socket file [which is just a copy-paste of one of the answer]

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API
PartOf=docker.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

This is the error I am getting error while starting docker.socket

```
sudo systemctl start docker.socket

See "systemctl status docker.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

output of "systemctl status docker.socket"

```
systemctl status docker.socket

systemd[1]: Socket service docker.service not loaded, refusing.
systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Docker Socket for the API.
```

docker version details

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfca03
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:26:30 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

To me, it looks like that docker.service is an issue. Could you please suggest how I can resolve it.

Comment: Can you look in `/var/log/error.log` for any relevant errors?

Comment: @jakub - there's no error.log file at /var/log/ location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a docker.service unit file at either `/lib/systemd/system` or `/etc/systemd/system`.  Mine looks like what's shown below.

If you have one there, you can try to make sure it's enabled via:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
```

Here's an exmaple of the docker.service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: @sfttb103 I don't have docker.service at both of the location. In that case how can I create docker.service ?
Can I copy-paste the one that you have given above?

Comment: Sure, you can try that. Don't forget the systemctl enable command I mention, after you've copied it. If doesn't work, then my next advice is simply to reinstall docker on your machine.